# Rename files in a folder with substring of filename

Tags: batch-file, rename

I never wrote batch files before and now I am having a requirement of renaming every file with `YYYYDDMM` from the filename `aaaYYYYMMDD123456.csv`

The code below works if there is only one file, but doesn't work if there are multiple files.

```
for %%F in (aaa*f.csv) do ( set "name=%%F" ren "%%F" "!name:~3,8!.csv" )
```

In case of multiple files the last file's `YYYYMMDD` is renamed for the first file and all the remaining files show the error *"A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found"*

Comment: A trick I use when debugging batch loops is to change the `ren` command to `echo` so you can see what's going on.

Comment: If you're doing it all on the same line like that, you're missing an & set "name=%%F" & ren "%%F" "!name:~3,8!.csv"

Comment: Madhu, do you still have this problem?

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me resolve, it works fine now with below code..@echo off
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    for %%F in (aaa*.csv) do (
        set name="%%F"
        ren "%%F" "!name:~4,8!.csv"
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below:

```
@echo off
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    for %%F in (aaa*.csv) do (
        set name="%%F"
        ren "%%F" "!name:~4,8!.csv"
    )
```